# python: exception within a comprehension: can I get retrieve values of the loop variables?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Suppose I am parsing a fixed-width file:

```
file_format = {'year' : (0, 3, int), 'price' : (4, 10, float)}
for lineno, line in enumerate(input_file):
    try:
        fields = {k : v[2](line[v[0]:v[1]]) for k, v in file_format.items()}
    except ValueError:
        print("cannot parse line {}".format(lineno))
```

I would like to add to the exception printout the information about which particular field couldn't be parsed. Is there any way I could retrieve `k` and `v` values without replacing the dict comprehension with a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could shift the problematic part into a function

```
file_format = {'year' : (0, 3, int), 'price' : (4, 10, float)}

def build_value(v):
    try:
        return v[2](line[v[0]:v[1]])
    except ValueError:
        print("cannot parse line {}".format(lineno))

for lineno, line in enumerate(input_file):
    fields = {k : build_value(v) for k, v in file_format.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Python 3, and dict comprehensions specifically, but checking the bytecode generated for list comprehensions shows that the loop variables are just local variables, and are accessible in the catch clause.

This is, I am almost certain, undocumented behaviour, though.

Comment: this was changed in the transition to python 3. The local variables aren't accessible anymore.

Comment: Why was it changed? And why was it undocumented behavior I wonder? Seems quite useful and easy to implement.